# Display random products on product page of magento every time i refresh the page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to Display random products on product page of magento every time i refresh the page. 
I have tried finding the answer on google and some of the solutions were to change my list.phtml code. 
i have tried replacing

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

with

```
$_productCollection=shuffle($this->getLoadedProductCollection());
```

or adding

```
$items = $_productCollection->getitems;
$item = shuffle($items);
```

but its not working, Even if shuffle() would work on collections (it doesn't), this would only show the same products in a different order. i want my products which are on the later page to come forward.

Here is my list.phtml code:

```
 <?php

$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$gallery_helper = $this->helper('productlistgallery/data');

// Chech if Tm_SpecialPriceCountdown module is installed
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Tm_SpecialPriceCountdown')) {
    $spcd_helper = $this->helper('specialpricecountdown/data');
    $currDate = $spcd_helper->currDate();
}   


?>

<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

<?php // List mode ?>

<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
<?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
<ul class="products-list" id="products-list">


<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/product">
        <?php // Product Image  ?>            

        <div class="product-image-container">

            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" itemprop="url" style="width:<?php echo $gallery_helper->getListData('image_width') + 20; ?>px;">
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($gallery_helper->getListData('image_width'), $gallery_helper->getListData('image_height')); ?>" width="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getListData('image_width'); ?>" height="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getListData('image_height'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" itemprop="image" />
            </a>

            <?php 
                if($gallery_helper->getListData('active')):
                 ?>                
                <ul class="product-thumbs">
                    <?php 
                    $count_thumbs = 1;
                    foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image):
                        if($count_thumbs <= 3):
                    ?>
                        <li class="product-thumb">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $image->getFile())->resize($gallery_helper->getListData('image_width')); ?>">
                               <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize($gallery_helper->getListData('thumb_size_w'), $gallery_helper->getListData('thumb_size_h')); ?>" width="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getListData('thumb_size_w'); ?>" height="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getListData('thumb_size_h'); ?>" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php $count_thumbs++; ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif ?>

        </div>

        <?php // Product description ?>
        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="f-fix">
                <div class="product-primary">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name" itemprop="name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                        // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                        // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <div itemprop="description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-secondary">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> 
                    <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p class="actions">
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        </p>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                        <p class="actions"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></span></span></a></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="actions availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="label-product">             
            <?php if($_product->getNew()){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
            <?php if($_product->getSale()){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
        </div>

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

<?php else: ?>

<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $_columnCount = 3; ?>



<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php 
    $_productId = $_product->getId();
    if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid row">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-4" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/product">
            <div class="wrapper-hover">
                <div class="product-image-container">
                    <?php if ($gallery_helper->getGridData('type_hover') == 'carusel_images'): ?>
                        <?php include("include_gallery.phtml"); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" itemprop="url">
                        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_productId; ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($gallery_helper->getGridData('image_width'), $gallery_helper->getGridData('image_height')); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" width="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getGridData('image_width'); ?>" height="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getGridData('image_height'); ?>" itemprop="image" />
                    </a>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php if($gallery_helper->getGridData('type_hover') == 'thumbnails'): ?>
                        <ul class="product-thumbs">
                            <?php  $count_thumbs = 1; foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image): ?>
                                <?php if($count_thumbs <= 3): ?>
                                <li class="product-thumb">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $image->getFile())->resize($gallery_helper->getGridData('image_width')); ?>">
                                       <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize($gallery_helper->getGridData('thumb_size_w'), $gallery_helper->getGridData('thumb_size_h')); ?>" width="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getGridData('thumb_size_w'); ?>" height="<?php echo $gallery_helper->getGridData('thumb_size_h'); ?>" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php $count_thumbs++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div> 

                <div class="product-details">

                    <h2 class="product-name" itemprop="name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                      <h3 style="font-size:14px;text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('artistname')); ?></h3>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

                    <?php if(isset($spcd_helper) && $spcd_helper->isEnabledGridList()): ?>
                        <?php
                        $setDate = $spcd_helper->countdownTime($_product);
                        if ($setDate > 0):
                            if ($currDate < $setDate): ?>
                                <div id="special_countdown_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="special_countdown"></div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    setCountdown("<?php echo $setDate; ?>", "<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>");
                                </script>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                    // Provides extra bloc->keepFrame(false)s on which to hang some features for products in the list
                    // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);

                            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    <div class="wrapper-hover-hiden">
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                                <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></span></span></a>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="label-product">             
                    <?php if($_product->getNew()){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                    <?php if($_product->getSale()){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
 if ($this->getChild('after')) {
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
    $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First Override your `list.phtml` file in your custom theme.
Add this code in your list.phtml file.

```
$productArray = iterator_to_array($_productCollection);
shuffle($productArray);
```

and add this `$productArray` in `foreach` loop.

```
<?php foreach ($productArray as $_product): ?>
```

`cacheable="false"` in your `catalog_category_view.xml` file.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"
    name="category.products.list" 
    as="product_list" 
    template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" 
    cacheable="false"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection is an iterator and not an array, array functions do not work with iterators. but you can convert it.

**Try this:-**

```
$productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$productArray = iterator_to_array($productCollection);
$items = shuffle($productArray);
```

Comment: i have used you suggestion but now all the products are not showing. Have a look at my list.phtml code